# Docker Tool Box VT Error in windows 10 home

Tags: windows-10, bios, virtualization, docker

When i tried to execute docker quickstart terminal .

it showed following message

"This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory"

But my PC already Enabled Virtualization. 
i checked "bios setting" and "task manager -> performance"

I am using Windows Home + AMD CPU

How can i solve this

---

Added

Windows 10 Home (Ver. 1803, OS build 17134.829)

I am only using window defender

Docker toolbox includes Oracle VM VirtualBox, so Oralce VM VirtualBox was installed with docker

Strange thing is that i am using App player

I think it is using VT

Comment: What version of Windows 10 do you have installed?  Please edit your question to include the output of **winver**  What security software do you have installed?  Many AV products have hardware virtualization features, when installed on a system, this prevent Docker (and other similar products) from using the hardware virtalization (VT-x or AMD-V)

Comment: What version of VirtualBox do you have installed?  This is a requirement since you have an AMD processor and are not running Windows 10 Professional.

Answer (score -1):

```
Open the Window Start Menu
Search for “CMD”
Right-click on “CMD” and click on “Run as Administrator”
Enter and run bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
Restart your PC
```

Here is a externel link with the almost the same problem solved - check it out
https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/4271

Comment: The author is using Windows 10 Home, which does not support Hyper-V, the command you are suggesting disables Hypervisor support.  **The command does not apply to Windows 10 Home.**